# Android Document Picker like whatsapp

Tags: android

I have been able to open audio file picker like whatsapp using following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
return intent;
```

However, I want to open the file picker in the same as it is shown in whatsapp. I am using the following code and other similar codes. However, I am not able to show document picker exact like whatsapp. The following code opens the document picker and it shows explorer and take me to Recent folder as starting point.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// The MIME data type filter
intent.setType("application/*");
// Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

It shows differently on different devices as well. I want to make it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for giving answer late. I don't know this is exact answer you are looking for. But i implemented image and document picker with below code.

https://github.com/DroidNinja/Android-FilePicker